# Setting value for autocomplete search field linked to Google Places API

Tags: javascript, google-places-api

I've a web page where people will be able to enter multiple destinations. 
When they state they want to enter a new destination, the current field values are stored in arrays. If they choose to go back to a previous destination, the relevant values are reinserted into the form fields.

I'm using the search field linked to autocomplete as the visible display of the destination.
When I attempt to put a value into the linked search field, the value is presented as if it is a placeholder instead of a value. Enter the field and the value is removed by the `onFocus()` event of the Google Places autocomplete add-in.

How can I reinsert the value and have it recognized as a value instead of placeholder.

**Field definition in the form:**

```
<label for="GoogleDestSrch" class="inputText">Destination: 
<span id="DestinationDisplay2">1</span>   
<span class="required"><font size="5"> * </font></span></label>
<input id="GoogleDestSrch" type="text" size="50" placeholder="Please enter your destination" />
```

**initialise code for Google Places API listener:**

```
var input = document.getElementById('GoogleDestSrch');
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
  fillInAddress();
});
```

**Attempting to reinsert value into search field when prior destination reloaded:**

```
form.GoogleDestSrch.value = GoogleDestSrch[index];


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Issue With Google Places</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js? sensor=false&amp;libraries=places&amp;language=en"></script>

    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    <!--
        var lastIndex = 1;
        var GoogleDestSrch = new Array();

        function GotoDestination(index) {
            var domove = true;
            if (index == 0) {
                index = lastIndex + 1;
            }
            else {
                if (index == -1) {
                    index = lastIndex - 1;
                    if (index == 0) {
                        index = 1;
                        domove = false;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (domove) {
                if (index != lastIndex) {
                    var doc = window.document;
                    var pdbutton = doc.getElementById("pdbutton");
                    var pdbutton1 = doc.getElementById("pdbutton1");
                    if ((index > lastIndex)) {
                        // move to next destination
                           saveDataF(lastIndex);
                           loadDataF(index);
                           lastIndex = index;
                    } else if (index <= lastIndex) {
                        // move to previous destination 
                           saveDataF(lastIndex);
                           loadDataF(index);
                           lastIndex = index;
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        var input;
        var autocomplete;

        // fill in the Google metadata when a destination is selected 
        function fillInAddress() {
            var strFullValue = '';
            var strFullGeoValue = '';
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            document.getElementById("GoogleType").value = place.types[0];
        }

        function saveDataF(index) {

            var fieldValue;
            var blankSearch = "Please enter";  // placeholder text for Google Places 

            fieldValue = document.getElementById("GoogleDestSrch").value;
            if (fieldValue.indexOf(blankSearch) > -1) { fieldValue = ""; }
            GoogleDestSrch[index] = fieldValue;

        }

        function loadDataF(index) {
            if ((GoogleDestSrch[index] + "") == "undefined") {
                document.getElementById("GoogleDestSrch").value = "";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("GoogleDestSrch").value = GoogleDestSrch[index];
            }
        }
    // -->
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="input" action="html_form_action.asp" method="get">

            <input id="destPointer" type="text" size="50" style="display:none" value="0" />
            <input id="fieldOne" type="text" size="50" placeholder="Tab from here" /><br />
            <label for="GoogleDestSrch" class="inputText">Destination: 
            <span id="DestinationDisplay2">1</span> <span class="required"><font size="5"> * 
            </font></span></label>
            <input id="GoogleDestSrch" type="text" size="50" placeholder="Please enter your destination" /><br />
            <label>Type of place</label><input id="GoogleType" type="text" size="50" /><br />
            <input id="fieldTwo" type="text" size="50" placeholder="Tab to here" />
            <br />
            <input type="button" value="Previous destination" onclick="javascript:GotoDestination(-1);" />
            <input type="button" value="Next destination" onclick="javascript:GotoDestination(0);" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //<![CDATA[
            input = document.getElementById('GoogleDestSrch');
            autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
            google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
                fillInAddress();
            });
            //]]>
        </script>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can not reproduce this, can you please post your full code or create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: The adventure of creating a cutdown version of the web app has shown the reason for the issue and the answer.   After setting the value, I am changing the display of the Next and Previous Destination buttons.   That is what causes the problem.   If I leave them visible (I am about to experiment with disabling them), the field works perfectly.    Code causing the issue (assuming ID allocated to Previous button) is pdbutton1.style.display = "inline";

Comment: Please ignore previous as it was a furfy solution... search & select destination, press next destination, add another destination, press Next destination, tab through fields to get placeholder text back, return to first destination, click in destination and then tab out....

Comment: Sorry, newby to here and having trouble uploading my code....

Comment: Well I have just wasted the last hour trying to work out how to get the stupid code up onto this page.   Apparently I am not blocking the code somewhere but I cannot see where.... a little hint as to which line was causing the issue would be nice....

Comment: some of the code is now showing and chunks are missing due to the editor hiding it... sorry, best I can do...